# How to show an overlay when pulled from top similar to the Quick Settings overlay in SystemUI application?

Tags: android, android-layout, overlay, android-statusbar

I have an application in which i want to hide the android status bar and make my application fullscreen. I have a set of indicator icons shown at the top row in a horizontal linear layout with a downward arrow at the middle of the view. On dragging the arrow down, i want to resize the view and show some detailed information of the indicators. This overlay should be pulled down above whatever existing content is present in my application till 50% of the height with the bottom background content losing focus and getting blurred. Something similar to the Status bar and Quick Settings overlay of SystemUI aosp application. How can i achieve this??